# how to load fragment in kotlin by passing just its name?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

i want to load fragment by passing just its name but it wont work anyone helpme out plz.
here is the code ---------------------------------

```
fun loadFragment(request: String)
    {
        val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
        var fragment: Fragment? = null
        if(request.equals(getString(R.string.keywords),ignoreCase = true))
        {
            fragment=AddNewKeyword()
        }
        ft.replace(R.id.containerLayout, fragment!!)
        ft.commit()

    }
```

Comment: can you share the errors which you faced while implement this i mean like the Logcat and also can you share what that AddNewKeyword() is?.

Comment: that is the fragment and i cant face any error but fragment isn't loading

Comment: (activity as RulesActivity?)!!.add.setOnClickListener {
            (activity as RulesActivity?)!!.loadFragment(getString(R.string.keywords))
        }

Comment: What you are trying to do is already implemented by android it is called navigation manager try to refer it https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to implement the Navigation Component, it will not only be dynamic to navigate between fragments, will be also more powerful.

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: cant understand